# Angular <a> ng-click function validate before redirect

Tags: angularjs

I currently have a user input and an Go tag (code below). I'm trying to validate the user's input on the click of the "Go" button. But the page keep redirecting regardless of validation.

I feel like it'd be best to just use the `href` to go the the `event/:eventid` route. Is there a way to validate it before the page redirects? Thanks!

**view**

```
<div class="small-9 columns">
    <input ng-model="vm.eventid" class="event-id" type="text" placeholder="Event ID" maxlength="7">
</div>
<div class="small-3 columns">
    <a ng-click="vm.validate()" href="/#/event/{{ vm.eventid }}" class="button postfix event-submit">Go</a>
</div>
<div role="alert" ng-show="vm.formError" class="alert alert-danger">{{ vm.formError }}</div>
```

**controller**

```
(function() {

    angular
        .module('eventApp')
        .controller('homeCtrl', homeCtrl);

    homeCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function homeCtrl ($scope) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.title = "Monitor";

        vm.formData = {};
        vm.validate = function() {
            vm.formError = "";
            if (!vm.eventid) {
                vm.formError = "Please enter Event ID";
                $event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            } else {
                vm.formError = vm.eventid + " entered";
                $event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        };
    }

})();
```

Comment: What about creating a function that should validate and redirect you directly instead of using the href tag ?

Comment: That's a good thought, I didn't know if redirecting from within the controller would be a bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be passing in the `$event` object from your template into the controller. You should also use [`ng-href`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref) instead of `href` in anchor tags when using Angular. So your code should look like this:

```
vm.validate = function($event) {
            vm.formError = "";
            if (!vm.eventid) {
                vm.formError = "Please enter Event ID";
                $event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            } else {
                vm.formError = vm.eventid + " entered";
                $event.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        };
```

And your template:

```
<div class="small-3 columns">
    <a ng-click="vm.validate($event)" ng-href="/#/event/{{ vm.eventid }}" class="button postfix event-submit">Go</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That worked to fix my error messages not showing up, thanks. But my page still redirects upon clicking the <a> tag.

Comment: Actually, I had a script that I'd custom written to manager the button before, so it was running a function to redirect, haha. I simply removed the script and the page now no longer reloads!

Comment: I removed all content from the `else` part in hopes it would now redirect when clicked and no errors, but it does nothing. Do you know if adding `ng-click` prevents an `a` tag from working properly?

Comment: I updated the answer to account for using `ng-href`. You shouldn't use `href` when using Angular.

Comment: Do you think it's better practice then, to redirect within the controller rather than using an `<a>` tag? So just use a form and ng-submit then the controller would redirect the page.

Comment: I don't know if it's "better" or not honestly. I do know that on the last application I built, I started out using anchor tags for navigation, but then the rules when navigating became complex so I moved all my custom navigation logic into the controller. If you did that, you wouldn't have to ever use anchor tags. Just call your function in ng-click and pass whatever ids or parameters that you need to know where and how to navigate.